# Python assign variable names to if else function

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

```
# Determine price per pound
if quantity >= 40:
    print('Cost of coffee $', format(quantity * 7.50,'.2f'),sep='')
else:
    if quantity >= 20:
        print ('Cost of coffee $', format(quantity * 8.75, '.2f'), sep='')
    else:
        if quantity >= 10:
            print ('Cost of coffee $', format (quantity * 10.00, '.2f'), sep='')
        else:
            if quantity >= 1 or quantity <= 9:
                print ('Cost of coffee $', format (quantity * 12.00, '.2f'), sep='')
```

Im trying to figure out how I get the total (cost per pound * quantity entered) assigned to a variable. I need to be able to take the total before tax and multiple it by 7% tax. Above is the formula I have to find out how much it will cost based on the quantity and price.

Comment: Start by fixing your indentation.

Comment: python has an `elif` block

Comment: What should happen if `quantity` is greater than 9 and less than 10?

Comment: @PM2Ring its only whole numbers being entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'll need to use another variable to keep track of the total cost, for this I'll use total. Then we can set that equal to `quantity * price` using the flow controls. For this you'll want to look further into using [if, elif, else](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

After that you can use the total to calculate the tax, which is pretty straight forward.

Finally you can use the same print statement you had in each if statement to output the total cost.

```
# initialize a variable to keep track of the total
total = 0

# Determine price per pound
# use if elif
if quantity >= 40:
    total = quantity * 7.50
elif quantity >= 20:
    total = quantity * 8.75
elif quantity >= 10:
    total = quantity * 10.00
else:
    total = quantity * 12.00


# do the tax calculations using total
total = total * 1.07

# print the result
print('Cost of coffee $', format(total,'.2f'), sep='')
```

If you want to calculate and use the tax separately, you'll need to use another variable. Just like the example above used total. This time we'll add a variable called tax.

Then we'll add another print statement to output it.

```
# initialize a variable to keep track of the total
total = 0

# Determine price per pound
# use if elif
if quantity >= 40:
    total = quantity * 7.50
elif quantity >= 20:
    total = quantity * 8.75
elif quantity >= 10:
    total = quantity * 10.00
else:
    total = quantity * 12.00


# do the tax calculations assigning it to a different variable
tax = total * 0.07

# add the tax to the total
total = total + tax

# print the tax
print('Tax $', format(tax,'.2f'), sep='')

# print the total
print('Cost of coffee $', format(total,'.2f'), sep='')
```

Comment: I would change that first condition to `if 1 <= quantity <= 9`. You'll also have to adjust the other conditions, since right now, it will always use the second condition (if it doesn't use the first one, e.g. with quantity being 100).

Comment: I think there's another brainfart in there, but for that, you haven't been the farter: I think the `or` should be an `and`, otherwise the condition can just be replaced by `else`, since any number is either greater than 1 or smaller than 9.

Comment: You're right, probably best to just replace it with `else` as long as it's verified that the quantity is greater than 0 elsewhere. And that should probably be done when taking the input.

Comment: is there a way i can add the total value to the if else block like I have above or no? I would have to switch it to the elif block to add the total value? @bmcculley

Comment: @mrsga16eats you should fix your indentation so we know exactly how you have your code setup. And technically, yes you could make your code work with the total variable. However, it's not a good way to write this and is a bit less efficient as well.

Comment: What if i want it to print the tax by itself first then the total all together? @bmcculley so I would want to print out the total tax before adding it to the total cost of the coffee...not sure if that makes sense

Comment: @mrsga16eats I've edited my answer with this example at the bottom.

Comment: That makes sense! so if i want to add shipping i would basically do the same thing correct? @bmcculley